# JavaFx: Where are the cells "moved" on scroll?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8, skin

I am trying to improve my implementation on fixing a `TableColum` so when the user scrolls the fixed column is ignored and stays visible every time.

The current implementation is quite dirty:

```
public class FixedTableCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

    {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            ScrollBar scrollBar = TableViewUtil.getHorizontalScrollBar(getTableView());
            scrollBar.valueProperty().addListener(TableViewUtil.xCoordinateChangeListener(this));
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(item.toString());
        }
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            ScrollBar scrollBar = TableViewUtil.getHorizontalScrollBar(getTableView());
            TableViewUtil.setNodeFixed(this, scrollBar.getValue());
        });
    }
}
```

Where `setNodeFixed`

```
public static <T extends Node> void setNodeFixed(T node, double value) {
    node.toFront();
    node.setTranslateX(value);
}
```

I managed to fix the header part, by implementing a custom `Skin` for the tableView and in the `TableViewSkin#horizontalScroll` I managed to set the header's `translateX` to the scrollbar's value.

But I am wondering where is the cell's X position set?

I tried to create a new CellSkin but nothing there, in this method of the `TableView` I don't have access to the cells, so I am now random looking for method which could be related to the `X` coordinate change of the cell, but I don't really get the appropriate way to do it.

The question is: Where is the place/ Which method is that, that is responsible for setting the cell's X coordinate when the `tableView` is scrolled horizontally?

Comment: have a look at TableView2 of controlsfx ..

Comment: Is that available for JavaFx8 ? Or just for 11 ?

Comment: how about looking ;) Chances are better for fx8 than fx11, suspect that migration would happen to fx12 (due to missing api in-between), not sure how far they are (wrote my own for a customer recently, was not purely fun ... ;)

Comment: I am trying but it seems I miss something... I have controlsfx in my project the version 8.40.14 but it doesn't contain the TableView2 and I cannot manage to get it, I don't really know why...

Comment: It worked with version 8.40.15, thanks for the suggestion :)